# jQuery and Zotero

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use jQuery in Zotero translators?

**update**

problem is that translators runs in sandbox, and there is no document object so jquery or sizzle returns following error: `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: jQuery is just JavaScript. If you can use JavaScript, you can use jQuery.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/group/zotero-dev/browse_thread/thread/dcb20b9127c4ec7e?pli=1  **or** https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/zotero-dev/3LILkSfE7H4/TibvBYX-wKcJ this should help cherrios bruv!!

Comment: @Tats_innit the page is old and links are beaked

Comment: @Reza: So what part of jQuery do you plan on using?

Comment: @Blender please see http://niche-canada.org/member-projects/zotero-guide/chapter16.html (document is sent as a parameter)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use jQuery in Zotero translators, no. My understanding is that the library would have to be included with Zotero for that and it's not.
Best idea is probably to describe what you're trying to achieve exactly and post to zotero-dev, there might well be a workable alternative.
Also note that Adam's translator writing guide is quite outdated at this point, so I wouldn't recommend writing a new translator based on it. There is no comprehensive documentation currently, though this page has quite a bit:
http://www.zotero.org/support/dev/translators/coding